# Why can this expression be rearranged like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Any good explanations why $(\text{high}+\text{low})/2$ can be rearranged as $(\text{high}-\text{low})/2+\text{low}$?
Note that $\text{low} \leq \text{high}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** It is just because of the identity $$\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{b-a}{2}  + a.$$
It is true regardless of whether $a \le b$.

To show this, start with the right-hand side: can you simplify $\frac{b-a}{2}  + a$ (by taking a common denominator, i.e. using $a = \frac{2a}{2}$)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you're waiting for:
$$(\text{high}-\text{low})/2+\text{low}=\text{high}/2-\text{low}/2+\text{low}= \text{high}/2+(-\text{low}/2+\text{low})=\text{high}/2+\text{low}/2.$$